# JQuery infinite slider - cut and paste method?

Tags: jquery, append, paste, cut

I am trying to create a slider that slides across the page. When the slider is finished scrolling I want to cut the `:first` element and append it after the `:last`. How would this be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#container :first").insertAfter("#container :last")
```

Very easy to do :)

[`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Comment: That looks easy, but I am still struggling. No idea why. I tried appending words and it works fine but my element will not. No Firebug errors. Debugging now

Comment: @RobinKnight Could you provide a demo or some code in your question?

Comment: Ive also added another question with some other problems with the Fiddle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930782/jquery-infinite-slider-simulate-the-macapp-store